# Android WebView and TalkBack Accessibility

Tags: android, android-webview, accessibilityservice, talkback

I am developing an android app where accessibility is critical. App uses latest WebView(109) to bring various content to the user. These content could be Epubs and  can contain MathML/LaTex expressions and so on.

By default, I would like to piggy back on TalkBack to provide the accessibility service,  however, when it comes to technical content (read MathML/Latex) etc, much left to be desired with talkback.

**I would like to either create a custom accessibility service or intercept the creation of accessibility tree as regards to the WebView on android to provide a custom virtual tree with translated content descriptions etc for talkback to deal with.** Is this possible ?

I have poured over various documentation and videos etc but havent been successful. Can someone point me in the right direction to achieve this , maybe a sample piece of code , repository etc?
I tried setting AccessibilityDelegate on webview instance etc.

I would like to retain the WebView/TalkBack combo to keep things standard except for the accessibility tree part.

Thanks in advance